# Lower and upper bounds in WHERE IN clause in PROC SQL?

Tags: sql, where-clause, proc-sql

if I first have defined a macro list variable of seat_numbers named "seat_number_list" and then I write

```
<

proc sql number;

select Seat_Number
from my_sas.names_and_wages_list
where Seat_Number in (2, &seat_number_list, 11) 

>
```

Does it mean that it will select only seat numbers from 2 to 11 including all the seat numbers inbetween contained in my list variable)? Are 2 and 11 lower and upper bounds of the selection?

Answer (score 1):

If this code works (it depends on what the macro actually looks like), then `2` and `11` are added to the `in` list.  They are not bounds at all.  They are just additional values.

If you want bounds, then use logic more like this:

```
where Seat_Number in (&seat_number_list) or
      Seat_Number between 2 and 11
```

Comment: thank you. what happens if the numbers 2 and 11 are already in the list variable? Are they then added on top of it as duplicates?

Comment: @AntonAmirkhanov . . . Filtering in the `WHERE` cannot create duplicates -- it can only reduce the number of records.  So, if the values are already in the list then the row is included in the result set, once.